# About the irreducible test for a polynomial over $GF(2^m)$ (its coefficients belong to $GF(2^m)$)

Tags: prime-numbers

For the *Miller-Rabin* probabilistic primality test, we can apply it to test a big number whether a probably prime number or not. Does there exist a method to test a higher-degree polynomial over $GF(2^m)$ whether it is an irreducible polynomial or not? Note that the coefficients of the polynomial belong to $GF(2^m)$.

This problem has been solved. Thanks the help from kelalaka.

Comment: There is a closed answer in Math [Rabin test to prove poly is irreducible over F2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1935795/338051) and here a concrete example [Irreduciblity Tests in $F_p[x]$ by Hyun Jong Kim](https://math.mit.edu/research/highschool/primes/materials/2016/conf/17-1%20Karnik.pdf)

Comment: Could you write your answer?